# Pasting into next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a code that will find a particular word on a page and then copy and paste all the cells underneath until a blank cell in another workbook. The only issue i'm finding is that the data shifts when i run it again and there is supposed to be a blank cell.

[image]

```
    Sub CopyRows()

Dim Found As Range
Dim ANextFreeCell As Range
Dim BNextFreeCell As Range
Dim wkDest As Worksheet

Set wsDest = Workbooks("sample_bills (version 1).xlsx").Worksheets("sample_bills")
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:="Description", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "ERROR"
    Else
    i = Found.Row
    j = Found.Column

    End If

    Do
    Set ANextFreeCell = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Set BNextFreeCell = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    ANextFreeCell = Cells(i + 1, j)
    BNextFreeCell = Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
    i = i + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 1))


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: For the first view looks like a solution could be to change by setting ANextFreeCell to a cell left from BnextFreeCell using the offset. Set  ANextFreeCell  = BNextFreeCell.offset(0,-1).

Comment: Gave that a go, but it just gets rid of Description 6 and 7 entirely in the first and second run, thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Find the last row in the second column and start pasting there (or at least the greater of the last row in the two columns).

Comment: Do you know how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Not quite sure how your code relates to pictures, but `i` is based on finding "description". Where are you looking?

Comment: So pictures are column C and D that code pastes to, and original workbook would have Description as a header and then anything underneath that would be copied until a blank cell, hence `ANextFreeCell = Cells(i + 1, j)`

Comment: And all the adjacent cells would be copied until both reach a blank cell. How would I start pasting in the greater of the two columns as you suggested? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Try looking up finding last row. You can probably transfer the data in one go too rather than looping.

Comment: Everything ive found on finding the last row on google, only finds the last cell in a specific column. Any advice on where else to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the last row for multiple columns, use `Range("C:D").Find`, add 1 to get the next empty row.

```
NextEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C:D").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
```

and then paste using...

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(NextEmptyRow, "C")
```

Comment: I have had to add `NextEmptyRow = NextEmptyRow + 1` in the loop otherwise each row continues to paste over itself. With this in mind, using your method, I end up with two empty lines of space inbetween each set of data (each time the macro is run), and if i have headers in C and D it leaves one blank line before pasting the first data set. If i change it to `NextEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C:D").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row` I get no blank lines between the header and data, but still one between each data set. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: This only happens if Quantity is longer than Description, when Description is longer than Quantity it works perfect

Comment: @Heba I was showing you how to find the last row/next empty row for multiple columns based on your last comment. I did not want to put the code in a comment. It all depends on where you place the NextEmptyRow line, it it is inserted in the loop it will find the next empty row for each loop.

Comment: Oh okay got it, thank you, im still struggling with formatting, but at least ive managed to keep all the data ahah